# Grouped uitableview with editable rows - Apple example gives me a crash

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xib

I'm trying to create a grouped tableview with editable rows (the number of rows is fixed).
I've found [this Apple example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20), in particular the section **The Technique for Static Row Content**. I implemented it, but the app crashed with this error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1262.60.3/UITableView.m:5494
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

I did all explained in the Apple doc:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    return cell0;
}
// section 1
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    return cell1;
}
return cell2;
```

}

cell0, cell1, cell2 are cells specified in a xib together with corresponding tableview.

The outlets and delegate are properly setted.

I know that it's difficult find the error, but any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the nib was loaded properly and that the values of cell[012] are not nil.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate a bit more on this? Where should I call initWithNibName, and _why_ should I call it -- shouldn't the cells be instantiated by IB?